# MySQL reserved column names

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1060

I just ran into an error in my personal CMS software where it would tell me that the database build process was complete, but the table i was creating would consist only of an 'id' field. After some trial and error, I tried getting the exact query it was using and executing it, and found that the problem was the mysql error "#1060 - Duplicate column name 'name'". I switched the column name I was attempting to something else, and it worked flawlessly. I'm positive it's not a reserved column name, because its used as such on another table in the exact same database. Has anyone else ever run into this sort of problem?

Comment: Uhm, it sounds like the query specified the column name twice... can you post the script you were running?  It's a bit hard to diagnose a script we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get an `#1060` error with your error message.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE MyTbl (id INT, name VARCHAR(80), age INT, name VARCHAR(80)); 
ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'name'
```

As you can see, the column name `name` has been used twice.

(Sure, it's not a reserved word, and sure, it could have worked in another table, where it only occurred once :-)

Answer (score 0):

For the reserved names you can write with `, like this :

```
CREATE TABLE MyTbl (id INT, `name` VARCHAR(80), age INT);
```

And remove your 2nd column called name !